# Chrome messes up tables in print preview

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have several reports that print tables.. [image: Print Preview with IE11 (table)]

The image is of IE11 print preview.. but when i do a print preview in chrome the table looks like this....[image]

I'm wondering if there is a specific css style that has to be used with chrome, 
the table comes out the same in mozilla as it does IE.

What am i missing..?

Thanks in advance